# How to re-write the following equation?

Tags: mathematical-modeling

I am a molecular biologist and reading a book on mathematical modeling. In this book I encountered the following algebraic conversion and could not figure out how the conversion is performed. Please let me know the steps in such kind of conversions and also recommend me some short text/easy literature to know, how one can perform this.

Following expression
$$
\frac{dP}{dt}=(m*(F-c*P)-n)*P
$$
was changed into
$$
\frac{dP}{dt}=(m*F-n)*[1-((m*c)/(m*F-n))*P]*P
$$
Best Regards,

Mazhar Hussain

Comment: This isn't mathematical modeling, it's just basic algebra.

Comment: If * is multiplication, convention is to not use the symbol in formulas.

Comment: Yup Robert... thank you for mentioning... I shall be careful next time...

Comment: Dear mvw... I am beginner to the mathematics... I shall take care of the point you have raised... Regards...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple factoring. Omitting the factor $P$ at the end (which stays the same)

$$
m*(F-c*P)-n = m*F -m*c*P -n = (m*F-n) - m*c*P = (m*F-n)*\left[1 - \dfrac{m*c*P}{m*F-n}\right]
$$

What happened here is something like this:

$$
x - a = x \left(1 - \dfrac{a}{x}\right)
$$

Comment: Thank you bartgol for explaining this...

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{dP}{dt} = \left(m( F - cP) - n \right) P = \left(mF - mcP - n \right) P = \left( mF- n - mcP \right) P = \left((mF - n) \left( 1 - \frac{mcP}{mF - n} \right) \right) P = (mF - n)\left( 1 - \frac{mc}{mF - n} P \right) P$$

Comment: Thank you BolzWeir for explaining...

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}P}{\mathrm{d}t} &= (m*(F-c*P)-n)*P \\
&= (m*F - m*c*P - n)*P \\
&= ((m*F - n) - m*c*P)*P \\
&= (m*F - n) * \left[\left(1 - \frac{m*c}{m*F - n}\right)*P\right]*P.
\end{align*}

The expression was most likely rewritten to account for a carrying capacity. May I ask what book you're reading?

Comment: Dear Nitin, it is An Invitation to BioMathematics by Robeva et al.

Comment: Thank you for explaining...